# Silverlight Toolkit Accordion ScrollViewer

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, accordion, silverlight-toolkit, scrollviewer

I am populating my Accordion with items from my database.  I have also wrapped my Accordion in a ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="LayoutScrollViewer">
    <toolkit:Accordion Name="ItemsAccordion" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AccordionHeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AccordionContentTemplate}"></toolkit:Accordion>
</ScrollViewer>
```

However, I cannot find a way to initially show the VerticalOffset of the ScrollViewer to 0.  It keeps on scrolling to the bottom whenever my database content is finished loading.  I have tried in the codebehind:

```
void CatalogItem_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebServiceClient client = new WebServiceClient();
    client.GetCatalogItemsAsync(countID);
    client.GetCatalogItemsCompleted += new EventHandler<GetCatalogItemsCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetCatalogItemsCompleted);
}

void client_GetCatalogItemsCompleted(object sender, GetCatalogItemsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ItemsAccordion.ItemsSource = e.Result;

    UpdateScrollViewer();
}

 private void UpdateScrollViewer()
 {
     LayoutScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
 }
```

This doesn't work, though.  I have also tried, in UpdateScrollViewer() to do:

```
LayoutScrollViewer.IsHitTestVisible = false;
LayoutScrollViewer.IsHitTestVisible = true;
```

which doesn't work either.  If I leave it as IsHitTestVisible= false, then it works as I would like; but I also want user interaction with the Accordion, so this isn't a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to do this but thy the following:

```
void client_GetCatalogItemsCompleted(object sender, GetCatalogItemsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ItemsAccordion.ItemsSource = e.Result;
    UpdateLayout();
    UpdateScrollViewer();
}
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.  Oddly, it did move the scrollbar to what appears to be about ScrollToVerticalOffset(90).

Comment: try scrolling to a negative offset, LayoutScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(-1);

Comment: Does this work: LayoutScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double.NegativeInfinity)

Comment: Well, I think I found the cause, but not sure why. The ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AccordionContentTemplate}" has a RichTextBox in there binding some content.  If I change that to a TextBlock and bind the same content, it stays scrolled to the top, even without the UpdateScrollViewer().  I am stuck without complex formatting for the time being, however.